# Как реализвать CSS дочерних элементов с селектором на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, css3

CSS:

```
details summary {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
details[open] summary {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}
```

Достаточно простой код, но как его реализовать в JS? Возможно ли это без if и прочего мусора?

Answer (score 2):

Можно получить всех html потомком свойством `children`, а там уже найти нужный и добавить css класс
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children

Comment: -_-

Все элементы у меня создаются так же js'ом, и мне нужно изменить стили у дочернего элемента когда меняется атрибут open у родителя.

Comment: Это хорошо конечно, но лучше это в вопросе указывать, тут не экстрасенсы

Comment: Понимаю, сам виноват( С другой стороны это всё равно не отвечает на изначальный вопрос - настройка стиля у дочернего элемента при селекторе у родителя.